# How to create custom transport for asyncio?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm reading the documentation for `Protocol` and `Transport` classes in `asyncio` package. Specifically:

> When subclassing a protocol class, it is recommended you override certain methods. Those methods are callbacks: they will be called by the transport on certain events (for example when some data is received); you shouldn’t call them yourself, **unless you are implementing a transport.**

*Emphasis added*

So, in principle, it should be possible to implement a transport, but...

> Transports are classes provided by asyncio in order to abstract various kinds of communication channels. You generally won’t instantiate a transport yourself; instead, you will **call an AbstractEventLoop method** *(which one?)* which will create the transport and try to initiate the underlying communication channel, calling you back when it succeeds.

*Again, emphasis added*

Reading the section on AbstractEventLoop along and across I don't see any way of creating a custom transport.  The closest it comes is in `AbstractEventLoop.create_connection(protocol_factory, host=...)` which only implies that it will create some kind of socket...

Well, my ultimate goal is to use a custom transport which isn't any kind of socket (perhaps a `StringIO`, perhaps a database connection cursor, perhaps another protocol).

---

So, is this just a well-intended but never implemented mistake in documentation, or is there actually a way to implement custom transport without monkey-patching `asyncio` and sacrificing firstborns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A bit of boiler-plate code is needed, although it's not too much:

```
from asyncio import streams, transports, get_event_loop


class CustomTransport(transports.Transport):

    def __init__(self, loop, protocol, *args, **kwargs):
        self._loop = loop
        self._protocol = protocol

    def get_protocol(self):
        return self._protocol

    def set_protocol(self, protocol):
        return self._protocol

    # Implement read/write methods

    # [...]


async def custom_create_connection(protocol_factory, *args, **kwargs):
    loop = get_event_loop()
    protocol = protocol_factory()
    transport = CustomTransport(loop, protocol, *args, **kwargs)
    return transport, protocol


async def custom_open_connection(*args, **kwargs):
    reader = streams.StreamReader()
    protocol = streams.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)
    factory = lambda: protocol
    transport, _ = await custom_create_connection(factory, *args, **kwargs)
    writer = streams.StreamWriter(transport, protocol, reader)
    return reader, writer
```

Comment: The [asyncio v3.7 docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio-streams) say "It is not recommended to instantiate StreamReader objects directly", with no reason provided. I'd use caution with this unless the docs are clarified.

Comment: @AndrewD'Addesio and then it says "[...] use open_connection() and start_server() instead". Here the purpose is precisely to write an alternative to `open_connection`, although I agree that this is fairly sensitive code.